# Is mootools alternative of jquery + backbone / spine / sprouteCore

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I was a full time java developer, now I'm also working with JavaScript and Android. A couple of years back when I started learning JavaScript, the first library I tried was jQuery. But it made my life harder, and after sometime I started writing fairly large a JavaScript app. It wasn't coming together for me using jQuery. I had huge a code base without much of a structure. Method blocks updating HTML blocks using selectors.

Then I tried MooTools and obviously as a Java developer it appealed to me a lot. And I was able to write managable web apps having huge code base.

As per my understanding MooTools is not considered a preferred way to write JavaScript because it mimics conventional OO over default prototype-based OO language. So now to really understand Javascript and desire of walking with the world, I decided to try other approaches, so again I turned back to jQuery, and realise that only jQueryis not enough.

So started looking at current trending frameworks like backbone, spine, ember.js, sprouteCore. Strangely I found that these frameworks mimic conventional OO like MooTools only by having constructors and creating a object of class and reusing this class object to create instance objects. So

- Am I missing something?
- Is MooTools really wrong?
- MooTools project is very alive and releases new versions/features, but I don't
  see many people talking about it on internet, also there are no
  comparisons vs backbone/spine etc.

Comment: Have you tried to do anything in JavaScript *without* the help of a framwork? It might help, in a back-to-basics sort of way to learn the fundamentals.

Comment: Frameworks inhibit your ability to learn and impose stupefying overhead. Avoid them at all costs unless you're in a giant bind. MooTools in particular is some form of sanity amongst mass stupidity, but it still is unnecessary for most JavaScript-related problems.

Comment: @MattMcDonald, are you really advising OP to avoid using all JavaScript frameworks? Really? That's a whole lot of wheels to reinvent. He obviously needs to learn the language, but over the long term, his productivity will fall off the table.

Comment: @MattMcDonald have you **ever** had a construct a product under time/budget/resource constraints?

Comment: @AdamCrossland But all existing JavaScript frameworks _are shit_. All of them, every single one.

Comment: @MattDavey have you **ever** had a product evolve past the constraints of generic framework X and then regret using said framework because it gets in the way.

Comment: I love the title of this question.  Its so subversive :-)

Comment: @Raynos actually yes but I didn't regret using the framework, because if I'd tried to build everything from scratch I'd probably still have been plugging away on boring boilerplate infrastructure code. I was grateful that the framework allowed me to get to the point that the product *was* evolving.

Comment: @MattDavey Meh, abstracting away "boring boilerplate infrastructure" code isn't difficult. Implementing it yourself from a union of small well designed tools is also not difficult. You would have gotten to the evolving stage yourself and be in a position where you can adapt properly.

Comment: If jQuery makes code *harder* to write you're either doing something really wrong or you're using jQuery where it really shouldn't be used (which is kind of the same). jQuery introduces lots of overhead and forces your style a bit, but if it's *adding* time/effort to develop something is *seriously* wrong and you shouldn't be using it for whatever you are using it to do.

Comment: @Raynos the whole "don't use frameworks" point of view is quite naive and I see it a lot in recent grads. I've spent enough time in industry with line managers telling me the product has to be finished *yesterday* for a budget of *£0* to realise that using frameworks wherever reasonable is a good idea.

Comment: @BenBrocka, I wasn't using it only for animations and basic DOM manipulations only,  I was writing single page, full ajax, web app e.g. Gmail. And you may be right, because it was hard to put reverse way of programming (using selectors) in my thickhead (thinks in OO an java)   at that time..  But still I don't like the idea for most of the jquery-plugins which always expect DOM element to initialize.

Comment: @Raynos if I do so, I would be working 16 hours and may be lose my job, because I am dependent heavily on frameworks and it works, For example I am using Openlayers, MooTools, MochaUI together, and Was able to finish up in a month, which I cannot imaging doing without framework, Only doing OpenLayers part may take few months. I just wanted to know that I am in right direction or not.

Comment: @Raynos, I'm sorry but your assertion that all frameworks are shit just doesn't hold any water. It's a meaningless statement, and it flies in face of the literally uncountable number of web applications that are using jQuery alone. Now, there's no question that every library has frustrations and design decision that one can quibble with, but that vast majority of programmers will use any framework's implementation of AJAX over rolling their own.

Comment: JavaScript can emulate class based inheritance and be perfectly usable.  It's not important enough to drive your framework decision.  Having a good API that makes you productive and doesn't get in your way is the bottom line you should look at.  JQuery *is* limited but can be part of a large app.  I'm doing backbone+JQuery+bunchOfOtherStuff for a similar app and I don't know how I'll ever know if I should have used MooTools.  AFAIK both ways are reasonable - nobody writes a large app twice to compare so these kinds of questions are quite hard to answer.

Comment: @MattDavey Don't get me wrong, frameworks are great when they can help you get shit done faster without getting in the way too much. However most JavaScript frameworks get in the way too much. This is a relative statement of course, it really depends on the developer.

Comment: @AdamCrossland then the vast majority of programmers are incompetent, doing XMLHttpRequests by hand is trivial, as long as your not catering to legacy browsers.

Comment: @Nachiket OpenLayers isn't a framework, it's a library to render maps. Of course your going to re-use that, rewriting it would be stupid. However libraries like MooTools only solve one problem which is legacy browsers, your free to solve this whatever way you please, I wouldn't personally solve it with mootools, but mootools can get the job done. As for mochaUI, meh all those UI frameworks shit out generic compenents and shitty code. It's a balance between quickly building mediocre shit and taking the time to build a proper custom UI.

Comment: 1) Learn Javascript. 2) figure out EXACTLY what features of ***x*** framework you would require. 3) Extract / find a alternative to said feature. 4) implement the 2% of the framework you actually needed. 5) ??? 6) **Profit**

Comment: ^ Time ultimately saved + no extra bloat + modular 'features' which can be removed / replaced at will.

Comment: And this is where this conversation stops. [Comments are not ideal for long discussions](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment), if you wish to continue this please use [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/programmers) instead.

Answer (score 4):

You aren't missing anything.

The *pseudo-classical* method of Object Oriented JavaScript has been an accepted technique for a very long time. There's certainly no reason you can't use it.

There are a couple reasons some people eschew it, though (myself included):

- It's a misdirection - the pseudo-classical pattern, by necessity, uses prototypal inheritance, but this is not obvious. People who like to know what's going on at a low level (read: me) don't like non-obvious abstractions.
- Purism - honestly not that great of a reason, but knowing how JavaScript works is good.

There are also several reasons that people eschew frameworks in general:

- Overhead
- Misdirection (non-obvious abstractions)
- Poor APIs (which obviously depends on the framework)
- Lack of modularity (they need one part of the framework, but don't want to load the whole thing)

The tendency, for people who want to avoid frameworks is to use micro-libraries, so they don't have to reinvent the wheel. Cross-browser XHR can be written in less than 20 lines (maybe far less than that). DOM interaction is similarly easy. Animations are less so, but there are still small libraries that can do animations. This is a modular approach that follows the concept of YAGNI, and keeps load times low.

jQuery in particular has a lot of issues. Some of which are solved by MooTools (which I'm just beginning to explore myself). Personally, I'm unfamiliar with many JS frameworks, but am exploring them simply for the sake of exploring them.

I find that since I know JavaScript fairly well, and how to properly construct object-oriented code in the language, I don't *need* a lot of what frameworks have to offer. I have no problem using the native DOM API. I have no problem using native prototypal inheritance patterns. And I have no problem using CSS for presentational bits (transitions in particular).

So, as I've become more well-versed in the ways of JavaScript, frameworks have become less of a nicety, and more of a burden. I keep my eye toward straightforward, modular code that is in line with YAGNI and DRY, and I think my applications are better for it.

Comment: Twenty lines for cross-platform XHR? You know it's *one* line in jQuery, right?

Comment: *sigh*... it's a 20 line *library*, which you can then use in a couple lines.

Comment: @user16764 [WRONG](https://gist.github.com/1887906) It's 7 lines with jQuery and 6 lines with XHR.

Comment: @Raynos Your jQuery example could be better written as a one-line call to $.post (not including the definition of the callback that you pass in, which can be of arbitrary length). So it is indeed one line in jQuery. Also, I find it very unlikely that your XHR example is the cross-platform code that Ryan is referring to.

Comment: Really? That's *exactly* what I was referring to. There is a minimal script behind it that normalizes `XMLHttpRequest`. So, if you need XHR (and only XHR), then you can use that instead of including the entirety of jQuery for one feature.

Answer (score 0):

If you are missing anything, I think that it is only that the large number of JS frameworks/libraries give you the option to choose the one that works best for you. I'm not personally a fan of techniques that try to force the round peg of JavaScript into the square hole of classic OOP, but my personal preference is well-served by the incredible set of alternatives to mooTools that are more prototypal.

Let's take a look at [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/): it allows you to write your code in Java and it translates that code into JavaScript to run in the browser. It's very unlikely that the resulting JavaScript has some quality of pureness or JavaScript correctness. It probably won't look good going through JSLint, but why would you care if your application runs the way that you want it to.

Similarly, the [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) language compiles to JavaScript and gives a completely different programming experience. Some people swear by it and couldn't go without it. Other people develop grand web apps and have not spent five minutes looking at it.

So if mooTools or some other framework presents a classic-OOP face to JavaScript, why would you care as long as you are productive and your application works?

Scott Hansleman called [JavaScript the Assembly Language of the Web](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/JavaScriptIsAssemblyLanguageForTheWebSematicMarkupIsDeadCleanVsMachinecodedHTML.aspx). After doing so, of course, he was immediately agreed with and reviled by large numbers of equally committed proponents and opponents, but there is a hard kernel of truth in it that any open-minded engineer is going to see. It is (in my opinion) to JavaScript's credit that it is flexible enough to be both a primary language and target for compilers.

As long as the approach works for you and whoever you are developing with and it makes your application work, go with it. Everything else is just some preacher shouting their special beliefs.

Comment: Raw Javascript has something else in common with assembly language. Just as assembly written for one ISA is not portable to any others, Javascript written for one brower's DOM is often not portable to any others. C and jQuery have the advantage of abstracting those platform incompatibilties out.

Comment: That is a very excellent point, @user16764. A good library like jQuery allows us to write JavaScript without worrying about browser quirks.

Comment: In the modern browser landscape, it is trivial to write cross-browser DOM code. Seriously.